# How to create macOS Big Sur-style Search Box with exterior focus ring in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

In macOS Big Sur, all the built-in search box controls have a glow around their exterior to show focus. How can I achieve this effect in my SwiftUI app?

[image: macOS Big Sur search field]

I built a search bar that looks similar, but it still has a rectangular focus ring which looks really bad. I can turn the focus ring off entirely, but that's not what I want either. I want the exterior glow.

[image: My Search Box]

This is my current SwiftUI code. Notice the `NSTextField` `focusRingType` override. With that, I am able to turn off the focus ring, but that's not what I want. Default gives me the rectangular, bad focus. It seems like exterior would be the ticket, but it produces the same result as default. I'm wondering if that might just be a bug in the current Big Sur/Xcode/SwiftUI developer beta.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBarView: View {
    
    @Binding var searchText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Search ...", text: self.$searchText)
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .padding(7)
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                .background(Color("systemGray6"))
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .overlay(
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(.leading, 10)
                    }
                )
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SearchBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            SearchBarView(searchText: .constant(""))
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 35, height: 50))
                .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
            
            SearchBarView(searchText: .constant(""))
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 35, height: 50))
                .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
        }
    }
}

extension NSTextField {
    open override var focusRingType: NSFocusRingType {
        //get { .none }
        get { .default }
        // get { .exterior } // same as .default, could just be bug in Big Sur Dev Beta 1&2?
        set { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Focus ring is drawn correctly by default, it just drawn around TextField, but not around your custom view with paddings, background, and overlay. I.e. everything after `.textFieldStyle` modifier is *not* TextField already. You need to use NSSearchField via representable.

Comment: @Asperi I understand why the focus ring isn't what I want it to be. I am wondering how I can get it to be. I tried using an NSSearchField via NSViewRepresentable, but it still just looks like a regular rectangular text field (like my example) instead of the search field as seen in the Finder on Big Sur.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure this out! This style of search bar is provided by `NSToolbar` using `NSSearchToolbarItem`!

Comment: Please share a snippet of your solution